# Secure WCF Webservice with high compatibility

Tags: wcf, security, windows-phone-7

I know, there are 1000x topics about WCF and security - seems to be a hot topic. I still want to get some up-to-date opinions about this.

I am creating a Webservice (free to use) where clients can register on my website, get a secure token, and can consume the webservice with this token. Consuming the webservice must be very simple independent from what language the client is using (PHP,Java,.NET).

Also I need to have one webservice-call exposed for use in Windows Phone 7.1, Android, iOS.

I've currently implemented the Service in WCF using wsHttpBinding and TransportWithMessageCredential security. Now I have already compatibilty issues trying to consume with WP7...

What, in your opinion would be the best Webservice/Security Framework for my needs?
* REST
* SOAP (With SoapHeaderAuthentication)
* etc...

Any feedback highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be consumed easily by different frameworks and devices, I would build a Rest service. Take a look at [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

You can use Web Api to return Json, which can be easily consumed by Windows Phone 7 apps, Java, php, whatever. You have the possibility to implement https and authentication.

Keep in mind that it's still in a Beta stage and that you'll have some issues accessing it cross domain, but it's a problem that can be overcome. I guess this will be made easy before it hits RTM.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Good to hear that. Still, whoever is going to implement that in php or Java will have some difficulties. I would go the Json route for better interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

Rest is easier with interoperability. If you do use soap then basicHttpBinding is much better than wsHttpBinding since the latter has some proprietary protocols.